# How to override WordPress title using plugin custom template

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to display a custom page using a plugin. It only shows when a URL is matched. The problem is, this page is 404 normally, since no pages or posts exists with that address. So it shows the 404 page title `Page not found`.

Here is what I am doing

```
add_filter('template_include', [$this, 'pageTeamplate']);

public function pageTeamplate($templates, $content=''){
    global $wp;
    if($wp->query_vars['pagename'] != 'forehand-news')
        return $templates;

    get_header();
    wp_enqueue_style('baseplugin-frontend');
    wp_enqueue_script('baseplugin-frontend');
    $response = wp_remote_request("http://backoffice.localhost/app/news",
                array(
                    'method'     => 'GET'
                )
            );

    //var_dump($response);
    //echo  $response;
    $divData = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    echo "<script>window.news = $divData </script>";
    echo '<div id="vue-frontend-app"></div>';
    get_footer();
}
```

The page shows and its content, but the title remains as `Page not found`.

How can I change the title or what is the best way to show a custom plugin page against a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code snippet to your active theme's *functions.php* file:

```
function modify_404_page_title( $title_parts ) {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        $title_parts['title'] = 'ADD 404 TITLE TEXT HERE';
    }
    return $title_parts;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'modify_404_page_title' );
```

Comment: Problem is I am developing a plugin and it can be used by anyone. So I cannot edit any theme's functions. So what would be the best way to do these whole thing?

Comment: @ShakilAhmed you can add the same in your custom plugin too. I just add the line for testing purpose.

Comment: Hi this way it works and also `pre_get_document_title` this filter works. 

could you tell me adding custom template using `template_include ` ok or there are any other best ways to do it? Thank you

Comment: But it will be overwritten when the theme is updated(?).

Comment: @peter better to be add all your customisation in your child theme, which will not effect in theme update

Comment: This answer just changes the page title, it doesn't fix the 404 HTTP code the web server returns to the client.